# ¿Cómo asociar un click con una letra?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, python

Estoy intentando hacer que dos botones funcionen como letras, es decir que cuando presione en el botón con la letra E sea como si hubiera presionada la letra E y que cuando presione la letra I sea como si hubiera presionado la tecla I, estoy intentando correr una tarea de asociación implícita y es necesario correrla en tablets por el problema del coronavirus.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen de como se ve la aplicación, la letra E y I y el espacio hacaen que cambien de página, es decir que cuando oprimo E la página debe cambiar. Pero si se fijan en la parte de abajo lo qua pase es que en el espacio se escriben las letras y la página no pasa.

```
class Constants(BaseConstants):
    name_in_url = 'iat'
    players_per_group = None

    LEFT, RIGHT = iat_order.LEFT, iat_order.RIGHT
    FIRST, SECOND = iat_order.LEFT, iat_order.RIGHT

    num_rounds = len(default_iat_blocks.iat_block_list)
    LEFT_KEYCODE = 69
    LEFT_KEY_NAME = '"E" (Presione E)'
    RIGHT_KEYCODE = 73
    RIGHT_KEY_NAME = '"I" (Presione I)'
    META_KEYCODE = 32
    META_KEY_NAME = 'Barra de Espacio'

    OR = " o"
```

Y este es el código que configura los keypresses:

```
const is_key_valid = (keycode) => {
    return keycode === left_keycode || keycode === right_keycode;
};

const mark_wrong = () => {
        $(".wrong_answer_mark").show();
};

const is_correct = (pressed_side, correct_side) => {
    return (pressed_side === correct_side);
};

const which_side = (keycode) => {
    if (keycode === left_keycode) return side['left'];
    else if (keycode === right_keycode) return side['right'];
    else return undefined;
};
```

Es el código del template

```
{% extends "global/Page.html" %}
{% load otree static %}


{% block title %}

{% endblock %}

{% block app_scripts %}



<script>


document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode === 69) {
    document.getElementById("ButE").click();
}
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode === 73) {
    document.getElementById("ButI").click();
}
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    document.getElementById("ButSpace").click();
}
});


    function AsignaValor(Nombre,Valor){
var Campo = document.getElementById(Nombre);
if(Valor==""){
    Campo.value="";
}else{
    if(Campo.value!=""){
        Campo.value = Campo.value + Valor;
    }else{
        Campo.value = Valor;
    }
}
}
</script>


<script>
    /*
    All variables which take their values from django tag should be placed here
    with ES5 format. I.e., use var rather than let or const.

     */
        var round_number = {{ subsession.round_number }};
        var iat_items = {{ iat_items|json }};

        var correct_sides = {{ correct_sides|json }};
        var side = {
            'left': {{ Constants.LEFT }},
            'right': {{ Constants.RIGHT }},
        };
        var left_keycode = {{ Constants.LEFT_KEYCODE }};
        var right_keycode = {{ Constants.RIGHT_KEYCODE }};

        var category = {
            'main': {
                'left': {{ left_main_category|json }},
                'right': {{ right_main_category|json }},
            },
            'sub': {
                'left': {{ left_sub_category|json }},
                'right': {{ right_sub_category|json }},
            }
        };
        var main_items = {{ main_items|json }}
        var sub_items = {{ sub_items|json }}
        var META_KEYCODE = {{ Constants.META_KEYCODE }}
        var left_category_name = {{ left_category_name|json }};
        var right_category_name = {{ right_category_name|json }};
        var current_item;
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'iat/lib/iat.js' %}?{{ seed_for_refresh_js_cache }}"></script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body').append("<input type='text' id='dummy'>");
        $("#dummy").css({"position":"fixed","left":"120%"});
        $(document).on("touchstart",
            () => $(document).find("#dummy").focus()
        )
    });
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
{#        <div class="row" id="progress">  </div>#}
        <div class="row" id="mainbox">
             <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"
                  style="" id="left_panel">
                <h2 id = "left_key">
                    {{ Constants.LEFT_KEY_NAME }}
                </h2>
                <div id = "left_category">
                    {% if left_main_category %}
                        <h1 class="keyword main">
                            {{ left_main_category|safe|escape }}
                        </h1>
                        {% if left_sub_category %}
                            <h4>o</h4>
                        <h1 class="keyword sub">
                            {{ left_sub_category|safe|escape }}
                        </h1>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% elif left_sub_category %}
                        <h1 class="keyword sub">
                            {{ left_sub_category|safe|escape }}
                        </h1>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="right_panel">
                <h2 id = "right_key">
                    {{ Constants.RIGHT_KEY_NAME }}
                </h2>
                <h1 id = "right_category">
                    {% if right_main_category %}
                        <h1 class="keyword main">
                            {{ right_main_category|safe|escape }}
                        </h1>
                        {% if right_sub_category %}
                            <h4>o</h4>
                        <h1 class="keyword sub">
                            {{ right_sub_category|safe|escape }}
                        </h1>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% elif right_sub_category %}
                        <h1 class="keyword sub">
                            {{ right_sub_category|safe|escape }}
                        </h1>
                    {% endif %}
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="wrong_key_box col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     Tipeaste la letra equivocada! <br>
                    En la izquierda. <span class="emph">{{ Constants.LEFT_KEY_NAME }}</span>,
                    En la derecha. <span class='emph'>{{ Constants.RIGHT_KEY_NAME }}</span> Presiona la tecla!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row_keyword">
            <div id="keyword">
                Cargando... Por favor espera.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="next_block_box">
             Buen trabajo oprime  <span class="emph">{{ Constants.META_KEY_NAME }}</span> para continuar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrong_answer_mark">×</div>

    <form id="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="category_table" id="category_table">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_table" id="item_table">
        <input type="hidden" name="keypress_table" id="keypress_table">
        <input type="hidden" name="iat_table" id="iat_table">
    </form>
</div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<body>
    <div align="center" valing="center"><br><br>
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <input style="width:150px; border: 0" id="caja" readonly/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
               <input type="button" value="E" id="ButE" onclick="AsignaValor('caja', 'E')" />   

               <input type="button" value="ESPACIO" id="ButSpace" onclick="AsignaValor('caja', ' ')" /> 

               <input type="button" value="I" id="ButI" onclick="AsignaValor('caja', 'I')" />      
               </td>  
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

No tengo idea de cómo hacer para que cada click se asocie con una letra para que el programa me guarde las respuestas.

Comment: Averigua sobre los eventos onClick y onkeyup de javascript.

Comment: Necesitamos un ejemplo mínimo y verificable de tu código amigo, edita por favor y agrega lo que llevas, además explica mejor el resultado deseado

Comment: Hola @BetaM creo que ya puse el código de lo que estoy haciendo, tal vez así me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando data-attribute.
Si quieres un ejemplo con **JQuery** me dices, espero te sirva.

```js
let btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1')
let btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2')
let btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3')
let input = document.getElementById('texto')

let getLetra = function(){
  let letra = this.dataset.letra

  input.value += letra
}

btn1.addEventListener("click", getLetra);
btn2.addEventListener("click", getLetra);
btn3.addEventListener("click", getLetra);


const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.addEventListener('keypress', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
}
```

```css
button{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button data-letra="A" id="btn1">A</button>
    <button data-letra="B" id="btn2">B</button>
    <button data-letra="C" id="btn3">C</button>


    <input type="text" id="texto">
    
    <p>Presiona una tecla.</p>
<p id="log"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Michas gracias @Aneudy, el problema acá es que el botón debe funcionar como si fuera una letra del teclado real porque a esas tres letras del teclado tengo asociado otras funciones, lo que tú propones guarda las letras pero no activa las funciones de fondo. Por ejemplo el espacio me ayuda a pasar de página pero con los botones simplemente me genera un espacio y no pasa de página. Quedo atento a si me puedes ayudar

Comment: Oohh ya entendí lo que necesitas, he modificado el código, revísalo a ver si esto te sirve! Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Aneudy Abreu, intente con el código que me sugeriste y sigue pasando lo mismo. Intenta ponerte un screenshot pero stack no me dejo.